# Field inheritance access in python

Tags: python, oop, inheritance

I have an issue with inheritance.

This is my main program:

```
def main(argv):
  rfp = reqboxfileparserng() # Inherits from reqboxfileparser()
  rfp.importsdir = './data/'
  if rfp.parsingasutf8_win():
    rfp.parsefile("./data/LRCv12.txt")
```

Here are the classes:

```
class reqboxfileparser():
  def __init__(self):
    ... removed code ...
    # Init mmap
    self.file = None
    self.f = None

  def parsefile(self, filename):
    # Public
    self.filename = filename

    # Init mmap
    self.file = codecs.open(filename, encoding='utf-8', mode='r') # open(filename, 'r')
    self.f = mmap.mmap(self.file.fileno(), 0, access=mmap.ACCESS_READ)
    self.f.seek(0) # rewind

    # Parsing stuff
    self.getfunlist()
    self.vlog(VERB_MED, "len(fun) = %d" % (len(self.funlist)))
    self.getfundict()
    self.vlog(VERB_MED, "fundict = %s" % (self.fundict))
... rest of reqboxfileparser() class code removed ...

class reqboxfileparserng(reqboxfileparser, object):
  def __init__(self):
    # Public
    reqboxfileparser.__init__(self)
    self.fundict = {}
    self.importsdir = ''

  def getfunlist(self):
    """
    Overrided method to load from a CSV file
    """
    self.funlist = []

    fh = open(self.importsdir + 'in-uc-objects.csv', 'rb')
    f = csv.reader(fh, delimiter=',')
  ... rest of the code removed, it works fine ...

  def getfundict(self):
    """
    Fills the fundict property with a dict where each element is indexed
    by the fun name and each value is an object from the model
    """
    self.__fundict = {}

    beginloc = self.bodystartloc()

    # PROBLEM!

    finalloc = super(reqboxfileparser, self).f.size() - 1
    ... rest of the code removed ...
```

As you can see I have two classes, the first is reqboxfileparser() and the second one is reqboxfileparserng() which inherits from the first one.

On the main program I call the method: parsefile("./data/LRCv12.txt") [not overrided] which later calls getfundict() [overrided] on the second class, but when I try to access f.size() it always fails with TypeError: must be type, not classobj.

It's been a while since I don't develop classes with inheritance but if I'm not wrong the concepts are right. I'm newbie to Python.

Any help please?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: It's worth noting the Python convention is for class names to be in ``CapWords`` - check [the python style guide](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/).

Comment: Could you post the error message, not describe it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are two issues at hand here:

## Super and old-style classes:

`class reqboxfileparser():` does not inherit from `object`, as a consequence, `super(reqboxfileparser, self)` will always yield the error:

`TypeError: must be type, not classobj`.

## Improper super call in inheriting classes:

You're doing `super(reqboxfileparser, self)`, but you're passing the inherited class (`reqboxfileparser`) as first argument, not the inheriting class.

As a consequence, Python would try to find a class that `reqboxfileparser` inherits from which implements what you're looking for you're looking for: `f`.

But that's not want you want: what you want an ancestor of `reqboxfileparserng` that implements `f`; that would be `reqboxfileparser`.

Please [have a look at the documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#super) for the most common `super` call syntax.

## Your solution

You probably guessed by now that you should be using `super(reqboxfileparserng, self)` instead.

Plus, you should always be using [new-style classes](http://docs.python.org/glossary.html#term-new-style-class) (But that alone wouldn't solve your issue, you would get a different error complaining that`AttributeError: 'super' object has no attribute 'f'`, which would be `True`, as `object` does not provide `f`).

## One last thing...

But here, you have one last issue!

You're trying to refer to `f` which is an attribute of the instance of the child class. This attribute is not present when you use the `super` call as it's not present in the class definition of the parent, which is the one the `super` call will use. (It's in the `__init__` method)

I won't go into much more detail as to why this matters for super, but the idea is to basically use `super` only for stuff defined at class-level. Usually, methods are, so they're great candidates for `super` calls.

Here's an example describing what I mean:

```
class reqboxfileparser():
    g = 'THIS IS G'

    def __init__(self):
        self.f = 'THIS IS F'
        self.g = 'THIS IS NEW G'

    def get_g(self):
        return self.g

class reqboxfileparserng(reqboxfileparser, object):
    def __init__(self):
        reqboxfileparser.__init__(self)


    def getfundict(self):
        print super(reqboxfileparserng, self).g # Prints "THIS IS G"
        print super(reqboxfileparserng, self).get_g() # Prints "THIS IS NEW G"
        print super(reqboxfileparserng, self).f # This raises an AttributeError

if __name__ == '__main__':
    o = reqboxfileparserng()
    o.getfundict()
```

Overall, a `super` call is pretty similar to using `ParentClass.stuff`, only it deals with multiple inheritance better, and should be used for this reason.

You can see that here, `reqboxfileparser.f` would raise an `AttributeError`.

---

Footnote: a `classobj` is an old-style class, a `type` is a new-style class.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer Thomas, but I still don't fully get it. I changed the class reqboxfileparser(object), so it inherits from object, and I changed father = super(reqboxfileparserng, self), and then call it separately finalloc = father.f.size() - 1. What I don't understand is still get the error you say: AttributeError: 'super' object has no attribute 'f'. Shouldn't I be referencing reqboxfileparser by using the super on that way?

Comment: @AlbertDeLaFuente I could help you if you told me what don't fully get yet?

Comment: Sorry, I hit enter to early, I edited the prior post. Thanks again!

Answer (score 3):

The point you're missing is that `f` is an attribute of the *current* class. It's inherited: when you call `super(...).__init__()`, the code sets `f` on `self`. So to access it from the subclass, you just do `self.f`, just like any other attribute.

The same is true of any attribute or method. You only need to use `super` when your subclass has actually overridden something, and you need to call the superclass's version. So there's no need to call super to get access to `parsefile`, for example: `self.parsefile()` would do fine.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer Daniel. I think I might have forgotten the self from the beginning in first place and I thought it was an inheritance issue... I'm a genius! =(

Comment: What are the `...` exactly in `super(...).__init__()`?